# How to fill the space gap when replacing a notebook hard drive for a slimmer one?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I just changed my notebook hard drive to a SSD one and it turns up that the SSD one is a bit thinner. I've read in a few places like [here](http://forums.anandtech.com/archive/index.php/t-2266802.html) and [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1719772/ssd-thin.html) where some have used a cardboard to fill the gap, but others said that this was not the best idea.

What material should I use? The gap is relatively thin. I've so far just used a cardboard sheet from a cereal box folded into 2 (and cut so it fits the ssd slot area).

Answer (score 0):

Try and look for a 7mm to 9.5mm adapter.  Many drive manufacturers sell drives with them already in the box.  You could look for someone who already had a 7mm slot and has a spare adapter or ebay or some other place like Newegg.

Comment: I've found this [rubber rail](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Original-genuine-Thinkpad-lenovo-IBM-7mm-to-9-5mm-hdd-rubber-rail-04W1640-new-/181412528863?pt=US_Drive_Bay_Caddies&hash=item2a3d0782df) in ebay. But Im unsure how I would use it =D My laptop has a hard drive "cradle" similar to the one shown at the last pic of this [Q&A](http://superuser.com/questions/375543/will-a-7mm-ssd-fit-in-a-9-5mm-laptop-hdd-slot)